# Использование typescript с Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, nextjs

Начал изучать NextJS, решил начать сразу с его использованием вместе с TypeScript.

Как правильней будет создавать новый компонент?

```
const Index = () => ()
```

или

```
const Index: React.FC = () => {}
```

или есть другие методы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы планируете использовать функциональные компоненты, то:

```
const Index: React.FC = () => {}
```

или

```
const Index: React.FunctionComponent = () => {}
```

или

```
type TIndex: React.FC = () => // return type

const Index: TIndex = () => {}
```

Comment: Если использовать данный метод нужно будет импортировать React. Может ли это повлиять на скорость приложения?

Comment: Если Вы пишите `React.` перед FC/FunctionComponent то нет, если не пишите то нужно. Почему Вы думаете что это должно влиять на скорость? Вы же будете импортировать тольк то что вам нужно и где это нужно используя деструктуризацию, например `{ FunctionComponent }`

Comment: Мне кажется что импорт модуля требует дополнительного использования времени и мощности

Comment: Next и так и так импортирует сам React, это же просто "обертка"

Comment: Спасибо, то что хотел узнать